# How to resize circle in d3.js

Tags: html, d3.js

I currently am new to d3.js and have created a small compendium for a site I frequent but as seen [here](http://irraquated.github.io/oras-uu/) The circle is too big for the browser screen, or at least it is for me.

My current html code can be found [here](http://hastebin.com/raw/xawunokixo)

Comment: you can change the size of the chart svg by changing height and width. 
and size of teh chart by changing the     `radius = 400;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your margin values are pretty large and you're using those values to set the radius of the chart as well as the size of the svg element. This code is setting your radius value to 490 (which means your diameter is 980):

```
var margin = {top: 500, right: 700, bottom: 500, left: 700},
    radius = Math.min(margin.top, margin.right, margin.bottom, margin.left) - 10;
```

This code is setting your svg element width to 1400 and height to 1000:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", margin.top + margin.bottom)
```

If you want to resize the chart, start by changing your margin values to something smaller. (This is also why your chart is offset so far from the top and the left...)